# Cannot find file or directory for installing Cocos2D

Tags: terminal

I'm following a Cocos2d tutorial and according to it, I have to send a command to a terminal to get it to downloads templates on Xcode or something. This is what it wants me to do:

> After you pull down the code, you’ll want to install the useful project templates. Open up a Terminal window to the directory you downloaded Cocos2D to, and enter the following command:
>
> ```
> ./install-templates.sh -f -u
> ```

I tried putting that command in but it said "no such file or directory". What do I do?

By the way, my Cocos2d is downloaded in my downloads folder

EDIT: I figured it out. I had to use `cd Downloads` to get to my downloads, then I had to go to one more folder. After putting the above command in, it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Type <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to open Spotlight
- Search for "Terminal" and open it
- Type `cd ~/Downloads/` This **C**hanges **D**irectory to your downloads folder
- Type `./install-templates.sh -f -u` to install the templates.

This should have installed the Xcode templates. Restart XCode and attempt to make a new project, you should have cocos2d options.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get to a particular directory in the Terminal is to do the following:

1. In the Finder navigate to the just above the directory you want to go to.
2. Drag the directory you want to go to onto the Terminal application icon. A Terminal window will open with you already in the directory you dragged.

From there you just need to follow the directions and type the following in the new Terminal window:

```
./install-templates.sh -f -u
```